# how can I move to the left a settings subscreen?

Tags: android, settings

I'm working with Android settings and using Subscreens works well for me. Headers on the left put up a subscreen on the right as required. When I select and item on the right hand side it expands as I expect but it fills the whole screen. What I would like is the subscreen that was on the right to shift to the left. So like a three level menu.
I'm newish to android so I hope my explanation is understandable.
How could that be done?

Comment: Please post some source code to better understand. Also add screenshot too, trust me, it will helps everybody.

Comment: Just to clarify, if you look at the following help page: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings#DefiningPrefs

Comment: Just to clarify, if you look at the following help page: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings#DefiningPrefs look at section: Using subscreens, look at Picture 3 . When I select something on the subscreen it lets me edit that but it fills the whole screen. What I would love to di is have the sbscreen move to the left and then edit the setting on the right.  This is for  a tab not a phone.